# what is dropdownlist.selectedvalue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have dropdownlist that read data from a table in sqlserver database 
That table has 2 columns ( ID , Name )
So I write:

```
ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
```

I want to insert item like ( -- Select Name --) as the first item in the drop-down list. So I write

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
```

My question is : 
Why when I select a Name from dropdownlist,
I get ddl.selectedvalue = the ID of that Name
but when I select `(-- Select --),` 
I get `ddl.selectedvalue = (-- Select --) not 0` ?

Comment: Try `ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple flow of binding datasource and adding custom item at 0th index in a `DropDownList`

```
ddl.DataSource = YOUR_DATA_SOURCE;
ddl.DataValueField = "Id";
ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
ddl.DataBind();

// ADD YOUR CUSTOM ITEM AFTER BINDING DATASOURCE
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
```

This means value at zero index of dropdown and text is "--Select--". Now if dropdown doesn't find text and value both...then it copies text to value field also..And that's why you got "--Select--" in value also
So use this

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
```

To specify both the text and value.So that you can get zero on selected value.